# Identify cuts and bridges in random graphs with R

Tags: r, graph, social-networking, igraph, network-analysis

I have this code that generates a random graph,
how do I identify bridges and cuts in the graph

```
library(igraph)
G <- graph( c(1,2,1,3,1,4,3,4,3,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,3,8,5,8,10,1,10,2,11,2,12,1,13,4,13,7,14,2,15,6,16,7,17,8,19,13,18,4,19,7), directed = FALSE )
# Assign attributes to the graph
G$name    <- "A colorful example graph"
# Assign attributes to the graph's vertices
V(G)$name  <- toupper(letters[1:20])
V(G)$color <- sample(rainbow(20),20,replace=FALSE)
# Assign attributes to the edges
E(G)$weight <- runif(length(E(G)),.3,2)
# Plot the graph -- details in the "Drawing graphs" section of the igraph manual
plot(G, layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold, 
     main = G$name,
     vertex.label = V(G)$name,
     vertex.size = 15,
     vertex.color= V(G)$color,
     vertex.frame.color= "white",
     vertex.label.color = "white",
     vertex.label.family = "sans",
     edge.width=E(G)$weight, 
     edge.color="black")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bridges" and "cuts?"  Are you looking to just highlight certain edges within the graph?

Comment: cut is an edge of a graph whose deletion increases its number of connected components. Equivalently, an edge is a bridge only if it is not contained in any cycle,   I want to know how to highlight the edges for that

Comment: And what to you mean by cuts?

Comment: @cmbarbu cut is an edge of a graph whose deletion increases its number of connected components.

Comment: if you only know how to highlight bridges it will help as equal

Answer (score 4):

Ok, given what I've been able to discern using the terminology as you've defined it this may be an approach that gets you towards your goal.  Hopefully it's helpful in some small way, though it's certainly not the most efficient bridge-finding algorithm (iterative removal of edges and counting of graph decomposition) it would work for small graphs relatively well.  If you need something more efficient you'd likely need to code Trajan's or another efficient algorithm by hand:

```
library(igraph)

G <- graph( c(1,2,1,3,1,4,3,4,3,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,3,8,5,8,10,1,10,2,11,2,12,1,13,4,13,7,14,2,15,6,16,7,17,8,19,13,18,4,19,7), directed = FALSE )

# Assign attributes to the graph
G$name    <- "A graph with articulated.nodes and bridges highlighted"

# Assign attributes to the graph's vertices
V(G)$name  <- toupper(letters[1:20])
V(G)$color <- sample(rainbow(20),20,replace=FALSE)

# Assign attributes to the edges
E(G)$weight <- runif(length(E(G)),.3,2)

##  Set normal vertices to black:
V(G)$color <- "black"

##  Set articulation points to red:
V(G)$color[ articulation.points(G) ] <- "red"

##  Set normal edges to black:
E(G)$color <- "black"

##  Set bridge edges to red:
num_comp <- length( decompose.graph(G) )
for (i in 1:length(E(G))) {
  G_sub <- delete.edges(G, i)
  if ( length( decompose.graph(G_sub) ) > num_comp ) E(G)$color[i] <- "red"
}

plot(G, layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold, 
     main = G$name,
     vertex.label = V(G)$name,
     vertex.size = 15,
     vertex.color= V(G)$color,
     vertex.frame.color= "white",
     vertex.label.color = "white",
     vertex.label.family = "sans",
     edge.width=E(G)$weight, 
     edge.color=E(G)$color)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to be implemented. As described [here](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2011-09/msg00008.html), you can implement [Trajan's algorithm](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29) starting with the function to find spanning trees:

`minimum.spanning.tree`

As for the cuts, the same source points to a different definition than yours but you may want to check it out.